# joomla 3 "**" stars around strings after changing database user permission

Tags: joomla

I could not save Joomla 3.1 admin options, so I increased my db user privileges. Now what I get is: 
[image]

That is "**" everywhere - in menus. How can that be solved? Language is set to english, SEF is turned off, DB driver is mysql (tried mysqli also). Help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This comes from debugging language strings. The asterisks are indicating, that the phrase actually is translated.

Go to the GLobal Configuration in the administration and select the System tab. There, set 'Debug Language' to 'No'.

Comment: Thank you! Some times it's funny how simple the solution is, and I forgot, that i did additional step to invoke this :)

Comment: Besides now that answer is here, I guess the title of the quoestion shoul be changed too to something - 'why there are "**" in Joomla everywhere', or something like that.